# Union and intersections of logical consequences

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a confusion with regards to the Tarskian consequence operator $Cn$.
I have an example where I am looking to find the intersection of 3 logical consequences but I am not sure how to find it.

$Cn(x) \cap Cn(y) \cap Cn(x,y) =\quad?$

I would say that the result is $Cn(x \vee y)$ because if I weaken the input $x$ in $Cn(x)$ with $Cn(x \vee y)$ and I do the same for $Cn(y)$ to get $Cn(y \vee x)$ I can get that the intersection $Cn(x \vee y)$.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or help me find materials where I can find examples about the union and intersections using Cn operators?

Comment: IMO $\text {Cn}(x) \cap \text {Cn}(y)$ is made of formulas that are **both** consequence of $x$ and of $y$. Thus $x \in \text {Cn}(x)$ but $x \notin \text {Cn}(x \lor y)$

Comment: Does $ Cn(x,y) $ mean $ Cn( \{ x,y \} ) $  ?

Comment: @JoJolyne I second shortmanikos's question, does $C_{n}(x, y)$ stand for the consequence closure of $\{x, y\}$?

Comment: @GVT Yes $Cn(x,y) = Cn(\{x,y\})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by monotonicity, $C_{n}(x)\subseteq C_{n}(x,y)$ and $C_{n}(y)\subseteq C_{n}(x,y)$, meaning $C_{n}(x)\cap C_{n}(y)\cap C_{n}(x,y)=C_{n}(x)\cap C_{n}(y)$.

Now, take $z\in C_{n}(x\vee y)$:

- since $x\vee y\in C_{n}(x)$ (given $x\vDash x\vee y$), by monotonicity and idempotence one finds $z\in C_{n}(x)$;
- analogously, $z\in C_{n}(y)$.

So
$$C_{n}(x\vee y)\subseteq C_{n}(x)\cap C_{n}(y).$$
Reciprocally, assume $z\in C_{n}(x)\cap C_{n}(y)$: by elimination of disjunction (given $x\vDash z$ and $y\vDash z$, $x\vee y\vDash z$), one gets $z\in C_{n}(x\vee y)$, and so
$$C_{n}(x\vee y)=C_{n}(x)\cap C_{n}(y)=C_{n}(x)\cap C_{n}(y)\cap C_{n}(x,y),$$
as you suspected!

Comment: That's exactly what my professor explained! Thanks for taking the time to reply to the post!

Comment: @JoJolyne You're welcome! Sorry no one answered your post before you professor had already explained the subject...